# TypeError: Cannot read property 'members' of undefined for Discord.js

Tags: discord.js

I'm trying to reference all the members in a discord server. It's supposed to log all of the members in the console. Though, it says that `members` is not defined. How do I define it?

```js
bot.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content.startsWith('!check')) {

    const list = bot.guilds.cache.get("335507048017952771");

    list.members.forEach(member => console.log(member.user.username));

    if (member) {
      for (user of list.members) {
        console.log(user[1].username);
      }
    }

  }
})
```

Comment: I think by passing an explicit Client ID to the get of ```guild.cache``` you will get only 1 member and not an array of members, right?

Comment: "its says that members is not defined" .. does it? or does it say `member is not defined`? or does it say `cannot read property 'members' of undefined`? those all mean very different things, it would be more clear if you simply copy-pasted the error message into the question

Comment: @Klaycon It says `Cannot read property 'members' of undefined`

Comment: @VedantBang How do I get an array of members. Also, just keep in mind I'm trying to give them a role, so I'm trying to perform an action on these members.

Comment: Are you sure that `335507048017952771` is the right ID? If so, how are you sure?

Comment: @Syntle I just found it off a site. Should I customise it to something that's particular to me? Is there somewhere where I can find the correct ID? Thanks.

Comment: Of course, you need to look for a Guild that the bot is in using their ID. Right-click the guild you want to get the ID of then click `Copy ID`, you need to enable developer mode though, here's how: https://support.discord.com/hc/en-us/articles/206346498-Where-can-I-find-my-User-Server-Message-ID-

Comment: @Syntle So would I get the message, user, or server ID for the Guild?

Comment: Server ID is Guild ID

Comment: @Syntle Thanks! So all I have to do is change the ID?

Comment: Yes, that's all you have to do.

Answer (score 0):

`cannot read property 'members' of undefined` means that property `members` of object `list` doesn't exist as it was never defined to JS exactly what it is. This happens if that's the wrong id or its not in the `cache`.

Your problem is that:

That's the wrong id or its not in the `cache`.